# Group Policy - BITS not applying on Windows10

Tags: group-policy, wsus, windows-update, windows-10, bits

We are upgrading our PCs to Windows 10 and are running into a few problems with updates.

**OUR SETUP:**

We have 2 sites based in the UK (Norwich & Preston) and we have a WSUS server in our Norwich site. Once we approve updates, the wsus server downloads the updates and pushes them out to all PCs in Norwich & Preston. We have this setup via group policy.

We have a dedicated 20mbps connection in Norwich and a dedicated 5mbps connection in Preston (as Preston has fewer staff).

We did initially have some Issues with WSUS sending updates to Preston which was flooding our connection. We Enabled BITS to limit the traffic during working hours. This worked fine with Win7 but we are having problems with Win10.

**THE PROBLEM:**

We are still seeing the Preston network flood when updates are being applied. This appears to be on Win10 machines. I can see the network being flooded and I can also see the updated being downloaded onto the win10 machines. When the updates finish the network drops fro 100% usage down to 40%.

During a recent update I applied the BITS setting manually to the local group policy (as it said 'not not configured') and I could see an improvement on the network.

**QUESTIONS:**

1 - Group Policy is applied on the domain server. Should the local group policy on each PC show the changed made? As stated above, all our machines say that the BITS setting is 'not configured' but we are confident that it is fine with our Win7 PCs

2 - How can I test that BITS is working how it should

3 - Is there a known problem with BITS on Windows 10

Comment: make sure that you have the delivery optimization mode set to 2